# Foreign key of child not added to parent entity when saving, one-to-one

Tags: java, hibernate, one-to-one, micronaut, micronaut-data

I have the following setup:

- Micronaut 3.x
- Java 15

Entity I'm trying to update:

```
@Setter
@Getter
@Entity
@ToString
@Table(name = "single_choice_question")
public class SingleChoiceQuestion extends OrderedQuestion {
  @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
  private SingleAnswer answer;

  @Override
  public void answer(Answer answer) {
    if (answer instanceof SingleAnswer single) {
        this.answer = single;
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("answer is not of SingleAnswer type");
  }
}
```

Its child entity I'm trying to persist as part of the one above:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "single_answer")
public class SingleAnswer extends Answer {
  @OneToOne private AnswerOption choice;
}
```

All entities inherit from this:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseEntity {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(generator = "system-uuid")
  @GenericGenerator(name = "system-uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
  @Column(updatable = false, nullable = false, length = 36)
  @Type(type = "pkg.UuidUserType") // Maps UUID to SQL VARCHAR.
  private UUID id;

  @Version
  @Column(nullable = false)
  private Integer version;
...
}
```

the base answer class:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class Answer extends BaseEntity {

  @Column(nullable = false)
  private Boolean correct;

}
```

The below lines are executed:

```java
@ReadOnly
public class MyService {

  @Transactional
  public <A extends AnswerDto> A answer(A dto, UUID question) {
    var answer = questionsMapper.toAnswer(dto);
    answer.setCorrect(isCorrect(dto, question));

    var orderedQuestion =
        orderedQuestionRepository
            .findById(question)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new NotFoundException("question", question));

    orderedQuestion.answer(answer, false);
    orderedQuestionRepository.saveAndFlush(orderedQuestion);

    return dto;
  }
}
```

*Expected behaviour*:
the SingleAnswer instance is persisted, and its FK is saved in the `answer_id` column of the question.

*Actual behaviour*:
the SingleAnswer instance is persisted, but its FK is NOT saved in the `answer_id` column of the question. They are not connected in any way, so orphan removal doesn't seem to work either.

After examining hibernate's logs, I can see it only executes the `insert` and does not do and `update` on the question.

Another observation is when I remove flushing, orphan removal does work - `SingleAnswer` doesn't persist, although the FK situation isn't resolved still.

```
orderedQuestion.answer(answer);
orderedQuestionRepository.save(orderedQuestion);
```

I can't see anything wrong with this very basic setup, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I believe the parent class for answer matters: how its id is initialized? Client side or generated? If generated, what strategy is used?

Comment: @Lesiak see edit

Comment: The only thing that is unclear to me in this scenario is whether both question and answer are inserted in the same transactional method, or the answer is added to existing question. In the second case, is question managed at the point of save? (I cannot reproduce it, in each case I get an update on question, as expected)

Comment: @Lesiak it's an existing question and a new answer. I also have a different subclass of `OderedQuestion` - `MultiChoiceQuestion`, which has a collection (One2Many) instead of a single field. It goes through the same method, except the `#answer` method inside the question adds the answer to the collection, instead of just assigning. Everything works for the multi one. (see full method in edit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was painfully simple, a `@ReadOnly` sneaked in on a class level at some point by someone, and I didn't notice

Comment: As a sige node - you don't need save/saveAndFlush if your order is managed (which it is)

Answer (score 1):

Include the `@JoinColumn` annotation indicating the foreign key in `SingleChoiceQuestion` entity:

```
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
@JoinColumn(name = "answer_id")
private SingleAnswer answer;
```

Comment: unfortunately, this doesn't work. To clarify, the column is actually there in the database, the value is just `null`.